# Use jQuery to make div value go up or down where $(this) is used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pretty good script that allows a user to "thumb up" a comment. The script uses jQuery to make the "thumb up" image green when the user clicks it. The user can also"un-thumb up" a comment by clicking the image again, and the image will go from green to white. Lastly, there is a little div that displays the number of people who have "thumbed up" a particular comment.

This is where my question comes in. As of right now, the little div with the total number of thumb-ups for a comment is not refreshed immediately when a user clicks or un-clicks "thumb-up." The number only changes if the user refreshes the page. I would like the div to automatically go up 1 integer if the user is thumbing a comment up (i.e. making the image turn green) and to go down 1 integer if the user is un-thumbing up (i.e. turning the image go from green to white).

The "little div" with the total number of thumb-ups is called expressed like this (you can see the full use in the second block of code):

```
<div class='upvote_count'>$total_upvotes</div>
```

I am having trouble because my jQuery uses "$(this)" and I don't know how to refer to another element... any ideas on how to make this happen would be very helpful.

**MY JQUERY:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.thumb a').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $img = $(this).find('img');
var $idshow = $(this).attr("id");

if($img.hasClass('thumbsUp')) {
     $img.removeClass('thumbsUp');
} else {
     $img.addClass('thumbsUp');
}

    $img.attr('src', function(_,s) {
         return s.indexOf('thumbs_up_green') > -1 ? '../images/thumbs_up.png'
                                                  : '../images/thumbs_up_green.png'                                           
    });

    $.get("thumb_up_tip.php?tip_id=" + $idshow + "&x=" + "<?php echo "1"; ?>")  

    if($img.hasClass('thumbsUp')) { 
        alert("up");
        //THIS IS WHERE I WANT <div class='upvote_count'>$total_upvotes</div> TO GO UP 1
    } else {
        alert("down");
        //THIS IS WHERE I WANT <div class='upvote_count'>$total_upvotes</div> TO GO DOWN 1
    }

});

});
</script>
```

**And here is my HTML:**

```
echo "
<table width='100%' class='box'>
<tr>
<td><span class='item'>$p[first_name] </span><span class='price'>
($tip_city_store$p[date_time])</span></td>
<td align='center' valign='top'><div class='upvote_count'>$total_upvotes</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='87%' valign='top'>
<span class='desc'>$p[tip]</span>
</td>
<td width='13%' align='center' valign='top'>
<span class='thumb'>
<a href='#' id = '$p[tip_id]' onClick='thumbTip(this)'>";

if ($upvote_count=="0")
{
    echo "<img src='../images/thumbs_up.png' width='21' scalefit='1'>";
}

if ($upvote_count=="1")
{
    echo "<img src='../images/thumbs_up_green.png' width='21' scalefit='1' 
    class='thumbsUp'>";
}

echo "</a>
</span>
</td>
</tr
</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can use a combination of `closest` and `find` to get the `.upvote_count` element relative to the clicked button.

Secondly, your logic is a little flawed and needed DRYing up. Try this:

```
$('.thumb a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $img = $(this).find('img');
    var idshow = this.id;
    var $counter = $(this).closest('table').find('.upvote_count');

    if ($img.hasClass('thumbsUp')) {
        $img
            .removeClass('thumbsUp')
            .attr('src', '../images/thumbs_up.png');
        $counter.text(parseInt($counter.text(), 10) - 1);
    } 
    else {
         $img
            .addClass('thumbsUp')
            .attr('src', '../images/thumbs_up_green.png');
        $counter.text(parseInt($counter.text(), 10) + 1);
    }

    $.get("thumb_up_tip.php?tip_id=" + idshow + "&x=<?php echo "1"; ?>");
});
```

Comment: thanks @Rory, ok reeeeealy close. Sometimes when the user loads the page, they have already thumbed up some of the comments, in those cases the image is already green when the page loads. Your code does a great job if none of the icons are already green. How might i edit it to handle the case of some of them already being thumbed-up?

Comment: @Brandon that state should be taken care of in your PHP. I think you just need to add the `thumbsUp` class to the `a` element if the `$upvote_count > 0`.

Comment: Good stuff, glad to help

Comment: thank you - you rock, PS what is protocol, should I remove my comment about it not working properly at first to make the answer cleaner?

Comment: No, that's fine. I don't think there's much protocol for comments, so long as you're not being abusive ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if($img.hasClass('thumbsUp')) { 
    alert("up");
    $(".upvote_count").html(parseInt($(".upvote_count").html()) + 1));
} else {
    alert("down");
    $(".upvote_count").html(parseInt($(".upvote_count").html()) -1));
}
```

Comment: repeating the use of `$(".upvote_count")` is not very optimised as it forces jquery to find the element again.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var upvote = $('.upvote_count');
var upvoteCount = parseInt(upvote.text());

if($img.hasClass('thumbsUp')) { 
    alert("up");
    //THIS IS WHERE I WANT <div class='upvote_count'>$total_upvotes</div> TO GO UP 1
    upvoteVount++;
} else {
    alert("down");
    upvoteVount--;
    //THIS IS WHERE I WANT <div class='upvote_count'>$total_upvotes</div> TO GO DOWN 1
}

upvote.html(upvoteCount);
```

Hope this helps.